# I am now finding some research to provide the argument below "Comparing to Realistic icon, Simple icon can speed up user's recognition of the icon "

Tags: usability, icons, simple

I am now finding some research to proof the argument below

```
"Comparing to Realistic icon, Simple icon can speed up user's recognition of the icon "
```

i found some argument with same point of view in NN/ Group article- 
[Icon Usability](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/)

> Keep the design simple and schematic. Reduce the amount of graphic
>   details by focusing on the basic characteristics of the object rather
>   than creating a highly realistic image in order to speed up
>   recognition. (Intricate details are difficult to distinguish at
>   smaller sizes.)

However, i can't find any strong research evidence behind this article,
is there any strong research evidence could proof this argument?

Comment: This may be what you're looking for: http://boxesandarrows.com/optimizing-ui-icons-for-faster-recognition/ - It has lots of references cited through out and at the end

Answer (score 1):

I have not done any tests on this, but I can make an assumption the more detailed the icon is, the harder it is to distinguish (As mentioned) and the more a user needs to remember to recognize—there is more detail to be rendered by the user. There's also many simple icons that are universally accepted and recognizable.

The following article has a link to a research paper that goes into detail about humans being able to recognize images that were abstract. It also goes into using icons + words. If you have space for words to go along with the icons, then that would be best.

[Link to Article](https://uxplanet.org/visual-perception-icons-vs-copy-in-ui-cd8e1a2f8af0)